# From ListBox string to Dictionary Key?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, listbox

I have a Dictionary(Of Integer,String) that looks something like this:

```
10, Bob
22, David
```

And I have a ListBox that looks something like this:

```
Bob
David
```

I would have thought this would be trivial, but how do I return the key 22 when the user selects David in the ListBox?

SelectedIndex is not useful on a Dictionary, unless I want to loop-n-count. The SelectedItem seems more useful, but all the examples I see use Linq, which I'd prefer to avoid. So for now I loop and look for p.Value.Equals(listbox.SelectedItem), which works, but am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the key of a dictionary to index into it, you'll have to loop through the elements checking conditions.  So you're approach of looping and checking for p.Value.Equals(listbox.SelectedItem) is correct.  LINQ just speeds up this loop search process.

If you really wanted to, you could swap your key and index of your dictionary, but that would likely cause problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `Dictionary` as the data for a `BindingSource` which will "map" the data to the ListBox.  This can have 2 direct benefits:

1. One copy of the data, period
2. The ListBox `SelectedValue` will **be** the related Dictionary item

It is very simple to implement:

```
Private mCol As Dictionary(of Integer, String)
...

Dim bs As New BindingSource(mCol, Nothing)
myLB.DataSource = bs
myLB.DisplayMember = "Value"
myLB.ValueMember = "Key"
```

Then `SelectedValue` will tell you which item is selected:

```
Private Sub myLB_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, 
               e As EventArgs) Handles myLB.SelectedValueChanged

    Dim n As Integer = myLB.SelectedValue
    Console.WriteLine("SelectedValue == {0} Related Data == {1}",
                      myLB.SelectedValue.ToString,
                      mCol(n))
End Sub
```

Output:

```
SelectedValue == 22 Related Data == David
```

You can do the same thing with a `List(Of T)` but you do not have to use a `BindingSource` to do so.  The item stored can be something more complex, like an Employee Class where you display the `Name`, but want the `ID` as the `ValueMember`.

When using a `List`, the Name property (or whatever you wish to display) of the Class would be the `ValueMember`; from a `Dictionary` the Class would have to `Override ToString()` and that return is what would display.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ:

```
public Int32 GetId()
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<Int32, String>(); // Your dictionary
    return dic.First(i => i.Value == (string) <YourListBox>.SelectedItem).Key;
}
```

Comment: My concern about using Linq is that this may or may not be available on other platforms/versions that we may target in the future. If I can do it through basic code I prefer that - although admittedly ListBox kinda binds me anyway...